# База данных товаров

Tags: mysql, база-данных

В системе надо реализовать 2 типа товаров, `линейка товаров (название линейки, а к ней модификации товаров из этой линейки относятся)` и просто `обычный товар`. Не хочу для этого делать 2 отдельные таблицы, а просто добавить поле `parent_id`, то это как то не правильно, так как при добавлении товара, и выбор линейки товаров (родителя), могут попасться обычные товары у которых `parent_id` тоже равен 0. Как по другому можно это сделать?

UPD:
Приведу пример: Допустим есть товар `HP ProBook 430 G2`, он является линейкой товаров и у него есть модификации `HP ProBook 430 G2 (P5T34ES)`, получается у линейки товаров `HP ProBook 430 G2`, `parent_id` будит равен 0, а у модификации `HP ProBook 430 G2 (P5T34ES)`, `parent_id` будит равен id линейки товаров. А теперь представьте что есть обычные товары (у которых нет модификации), у них тоже будит `parent_id` = 0. И теперь, при добавлении товара, когда мы выбираем линейку товаров (родителя), то в списке окажется не только `HP ProBook 430 G2`, но и обычный товар без модификации

Comment: `это как то не правильно`  Почему не правильно?

Comment: Добавил пример, почему это не правильно

Comment: Вы определитесь что для чего мы выбираем - продуктовые линейки или конкретные товары? Вообще, как мне кажется, есть два варианта. 1) Не лениться и сделать свою таблицу для линеек. 2) Отличать линейки от товаров по специальному полю, например data_type = 'TOVAR' / 'LINEIKA'. Ну и конечно всегда можно сделать линейку, состоящую из всего одного товара.

Comment: data_type вот это скорее всего и нужно. Если из примера не понятно, то вот гляньте сюда https://market.yandex.ru/product/10952997?hid=91013 и вот сюда https://market.yandex.ru/product/13334303 . Первая ссылка это линейка товаров, а вторая это модификация, то есть обычный товар который относится к первому. По сути это 2 товара, только один имеет модификацию

Comment: Уверен, что у них каждому понятию соответствует собственная модель и собственная таблица для хранения её состояния.

Comment: @Sergey Зря уверены ... если посмотреть по обоим ссылкам видно, что наборы атрибутов практически одинаковы. Если их положить в разные таблицы то еще десяток таблиц придется дублировать что бы корректно ссылаться на разные сущности. кроме того теряется возможность наследования атрибутов от "линейки". Древовидное хранение, предложенное ТС для подобных вещей оптимально. И да, напрашивается поле типа записи или даже какое нибудь булево is_line

Comment: Осталось узнать как обстоят дела на самом деле от разработчика магазина для яндекса

Comment: @Mike при этом foreign key таблицы продаж товаров, например, может ссылаться на линейки, что как бы совсем не уместно. Усложнять foreign key делая его составным? Ну и во всякие запросы не забывать втыкать дополнительное условие на data_type. Линейки и товары - разные понятия, разные сущности и жить должны в разных таблицах. И по ссылкам структура базы не видна. В представлении можно всё перевернуть хоть с ног на голову.

Comment: @Sergey Ну это уже ТС решать. я исхожу из того, что раз он задумался о наследовании значит они очень похожи. Да и пример хороший привел. Не думаю, что `HP ProBook 430 G2` сильно отличается от `HP ProBook 430 G2 (P5T34ES)` вполне возможно (как это в яндексе) я могу выбирать товар введя имя "линейки" а потом уже видеть конкретную модификацию и она будет от общей линейки отличатсья одной незначительной деталью

Comment: @Sergey На счет некорректности ключей ... Ну может у меня был в БД товар `HP ProBook 430 G2` я его отлично продавал, записи об этом есть и тут производитель делает модификацию и я в БД объявляю этот товар линейкой и дальше распродаю остатки просто товара, который теперь линейка и начинаю параллельно продавать модификацию. так что почему бы линейки одновременно не быть товаром на который ссылаются, вполне нормальная ситуация для подобных систем

Comment: Товар товаром и остаётся. Просто закончились припасы, остатки нулевые. А поступает новая номенклатура для продажи. Какие-то там линейки - это интересно только маркетолухам, чтобы окучивать таких же олухов-покупателей. А в учёте будет либо старый и новый товар, либо новый сорт старого. Если есть какая-то "наследственная" связь, то она рассматривается как сортовой признак, как и все прочие отличительные признаки конкретной номенклатурной позиции тмц. Можно конечно хранить такую информацию, но parent тоже будет товаром.

Comment: @Alex_01 если удалось найти своё решение - добавьте его, как ответ на вопрос. Возможно это поможет кому-то в будущем. Если же помог опубликованный ответ, то отметьте его, как правильный.

Comment: @Anatol Решение найти удалось благодаря всем кто принимал участие в этом вопросе (вы, Mike, Sergey). По этому я не могу выделить кого то, что бы не задеть других))) Само решение: bool is_group и parent_id >=0

Answer (score 2):

Если проблема только в этом, то поле `parent_id` должно допускать значения `NULL`. Тогда у линейки товаров `parent_id = 0`, у обычных товаров `parent_id = NULL`.

Comment: Если установлен foraign key, то parent_id может быть равен нулю только при наличии записи с id=0. Т.е. так же как и для всех значений отличных от null

Comment: @Sergey в вопросе такой оговорки нет, проблема у автора с этим не связана. Вопрос не про проектирование, ибо автор сразу заявил, что 2 таблицы делать не хочет.

Comment: Автор новичок и сам не знает чего он хочет и чем это может обернуться. Не надо давать вредных советов.

Comment: @Anatol спасибо, попробую с вашим решением реализовать

Comment: @Alex_01 Использование 0 для подобных вещей дейстивтельно не корректно. Ибо 0 запись должна существовать и это будет некая "суперлинейка". Поле типа записи "линейка/не линейка" (а возможно в будущем вспывут еще какие нибудь типы) выглядит лучше

Comment: @Mike значение 0 и подразумевает верхний уровень вложенности. Суперлинейка, на которую может ссылаться другая линейка. Значение `NULL` является признаком отсутствия иерархии. Добавляя тип, мы просто продублируем информацию, которая уже есть в поле `parent_id`, которое, в свою очередь, всё равно нам потребуется хранить.

Comment: @Anatol Да, но запись 0 в БД придется держать и она будет лезть во все выдачи товаров и/или линеек, придется по всему коду ее исключать из выдачи по id!=0 ... Это мягко говоря неудобно

Comment: @Mike а зачем исключать?

Comment: @Anatol А как вы эту строку назовете интересно "все товары" ? Если что, я говорю про строку с id=0, а не с parent_id=0 ...

Comment: @Mike, кажется Вы не поняли задачу

Comment: @Anatol Я думаю, что понял задачу. Но записей с parent_id=0 в системе быть не может, если нет записи с id=0. И вот что при этом означает запись с id=0 кроме как некую программную заглушку ради того что бы положить записи с parent_id=0 я не представляю

Comment: @Mike `записей с parent_id=0 в системе быть не может` Почему не может? Вовсе не обязательно так себя ограничивать. И не нужна нам запись с id = 0.Тем более, исходя из видимой предметной области, у нас всего два уровня вложенности подразумевается.

Comment: @Anatol Отсутствие в таблице FOREIGN KEY потенциально грозит появлению в системе записей с указателями в никуда. Контроль на наличие порожденных записей, перед удалением родительских придется делать руками. Работа с системами без автоматической ссылочной целостности обычно обходится раза в 3-4 дороже по времени разработки и сопровождения

Comment: @Mike ссылочная целостность может обеспечиваться за счёт логики, не только ключами. Вообще, полагаю это обсуждение выходит за рамки вопроса. Добавьте свой ответ, если считаете нужным.

Comment: Если посмотреть на api https://tech.yandex.ru/market/content-data/doc/dg/reference/model-id-docpage/#output , то там можно увидить такую  строку `"isGroup": {признак_родительской_модели}`. Думаю, будит правильно сделать буливо isGroup, и потом выбирать это все запросом 'where isGroup = true and parent_id = 0` таким образом останутся только линейки товаров

Comment: @Alex_01 а если воспользоваться предложенным мной вариантом, то запрос будет `WHERE parent_id = 0`

Comment: @Anatol, да, я ваш варриант не забыл) у меня сейчас 3 разных варрианта. Буду пробовать каждый)

Comment: @Alex_01 обратите внимание на рекомендации и замечания Mike. С точки зрения каноничного проектирования он прав. Я бы, например, всё же разнёс по разным таблицам и добавил ещё категории. Но Вам виднее, т.к. предметная область вся нам не известна.